# Buttons and segmentedControl on UICollectionReusableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am creating a UICollectionView with 2 sections. First section being a parallax Header and the second section header being a subclass of the UICollectionResuableView and it always sticks at the top. On the ReusableView, it has 4 buttons and a segmentedControl. Segmented Control is used for displaying the data in either grid view or list view. The 4 buttons are for displaying different types of data.

Everything seems to work fine but I noticed that when more data is loaded, at some point all buttons and the segmented control on the ReusableView stop responding. However the collectionView is still scrollable. After a few scroll up and down the ReusableView will respond again. Another problem that I noticed is that the selected index of the segmentedControl sometimes got changed (visually, display data remains correct) after a reload.

I exhausted all possible causes that I can think of... Has anyone came across similar problems? I am using Interface Builder and not storyboard btw.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same bug. Are you found a solution for this case?

Comment: Hey I don't remember exactly how I solved the issue as it has been a while. but in my case I believe it was caused by too many data requests at one time.